# I am integrating FolioReaderKit in project

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I am trying to integrate FolioReaderKit in swift, while pod installing I am getting Realm (3.13.1) instead of Realm (3.17.3). I have updated 1.11.2 version of pod.

What is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Run `pod update`. If that doesn't work, examine/share the the `Podfile` and `Podfile.lock` to determine why a particular version is chosen.